# How to add Firebase Messaging service dependency to Bazel?

Tags: java, android, firebase, bazel

Right now I have added these lines to my WORKSPACE file

```
# Google Maven Repository
GMAVEN_TAG = "20180513-1"    
http_archive(
name = "gmaven_rules",
strip_prefix = "gmaven_rules-%s" % GMAVEN_TAG,
url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/gmaven_rules/archive/%s.tar.gz" % 
GMAVEN_TAG,
 )
load("@gmaven_rules//:gmaven.bzl", "gmaven_rules")
gmaven_rules()
```

And in my BUILD file, I have added these lines

```
load("@gmaven_rules//:defs.bzl", "gmaven_artifact")
.......
deps = [.
        .
        gmaven_artifact("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:aar:17.0.0"),
    ],
    )
```

I am getting this error on running `bazel build`

```
ERROR: /home/user/Desktop/Git/SENA- 
28/tensorflow/Androidapp/BUILD:24:1: no such package 
'@com_google_firebase_firebase_messaging_17_0_0//jar': The repository 
could not be resolved and referenced by '//Androidapp:androidapp'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//Androidapp:androidapp' failed; build 
aborted: no such package
```

'@com_google_firebase_firebase_messaging_17_0_0//jar': The repository 
    could not be resolved
    INFO: Elapsed time: 0.237s
    INFO: 0 processes.
    FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/contrib/lite/java

Comment: See also this discussion for additional information on building an app with FCM with bazel: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/bazel-discuss/rizq2Es-Sjw/discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `20180513-1` gmaven_rules release doesn't contain v17.0.0 of Firebase Messaging. The latest version in that release is v15.0.2.

[I've just pushed a release `20180530-1`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/gmaven_rules/releases/tag/20180530-1) that contains the latest updates in the repository, including Firebase Messaging v17.0.0. You can start using it by updating `GMAVEN_TAG`:

```
GMAVEN_TAG = "20180530-1"

http_archive(
    name = "gmaven_rules",
    strip_prefix = "gmaven_rules-%s" % GMAVEN_TAG,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/gmaven_rules/archive/%s.tar.gz" % GMAVEN_TAG,
)

load("@gmaven_rules//:gmaven.bzl", "gmaven_rules")

gmaven_rules()
```

Comment: Hello Jin, Can you help me with one more thing? I have added dependencies for FCM but my FirebaseInstanceIdService and FirebaseMessagingService are not starting. Here is my [workspace](https://pastebin.com/X6MpJaVC) and [build](https://pastebin.com/X5h6bPf6) files. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's giving me this error `FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful`

Comment: Please start another question for that, since it looks like it’s more related to Firebase than Bazel.